# Grouping and adding results by month

Tags: php, mysql

I have joined tables with the following fields:

```
company   invoicedate   amtdue
-------   -----------   ------ 
ABC       2014-07-20    100
DEF       2014-06-20    200 
ABC       2014-08-06    300 
GHI       2014-08-01    400  
GHI       2014-08-02    500
```

At the moment, what I get is wrong:

```
company   60 DAYS    30 DAYS   CURRENT   TOTAL
-------   -------    -------   -------   -----
ABC        0           100        0      100
DEF       200           0         0      200 
GHI        0            0        400     400
```

It should be:

```
company   60 DAYS    30 DAYS   CURRENT   TOTAL
-------   -------    -------   -------   -----
ABC        0           100       300     400
DEF       200           0         0      200 
GHI        0            0        900     900
```

In other words, it is displaying only 1 of the amounts under the right column, but not adding them.
Here is my code:

```
<?php       
$now = time();
$result = mysql_query('SELECT *,SUM(amtdue)
FROM quotes AS ql inner join customers as c on ql.customerid = c.cid
WHERE amtdue > 0
GROUP BY company
')or die(mysql_error());

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))  
{  
echo "<tr>";
echo '<td>' . $row['company'] . '</td>';

if(floor(($now - strtotime($row['invoicedate']))/(60*60*24))>60) // 60 DAYS
echo '<td align="right">' . $row['SUM(amtdue)'] . '</td>';
else
echo '<td align="right">' . "0.00" . '</td>';

if(floor(($now - strtotime($row['invoicedate']))/(60*60*24))>30 && floor(($now - strtotime($row['invoicedate']))/(60*60*24))<60) // 30 DAYS
echo '<td align="right">' . $row['SUM(amtdue)'] . '</td>';
else
echo '<td align="right">' . "0.00" . '</td>';

if(floor(($now - strtotime($row['invoicedate']))/(60*60*24))<30) // CURRENT
echo '<td align="right">' . $row['SUM(amtdue)'] . '</td>';
else
echo '<td align="right">' . "0.00" . '</td>';

echo '<td align="right">' . $row['SUM(amtdue)'] . '</td>';

echo "</tr>"; 
}
?>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I'm sure you can get your result with a single query without having to use PHP for further calculations. But I don't understand your desired result. You should explain it.

Comment: Thank you VMai, the desired result is that the individual amounts are displayed under wherever they fall under(30/60/current) on the same line. Also, at the moment is does not add amounts falling in the same date range. Thank you

Comment: I don't know where you live, but here it's already the 7th of August. I think that's the source of confusion for me. Or should it be: current := current month, 30 := last month, 60 := second to last month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my assumptions are right then you can use

```
SELECT 
    company, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(
                      MONTH, 
                      LAST_DAY(invoicedate) + INTERVAL 1 DAY, 
                      LAST_DAY(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY) > 1 
             THEN amtdue ELSE 0 END) 60days,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(
                      MONTH, 
                      LAST_DAY(invoicedate) + INTERVAL 1 DAY, 
                      LAST_DAY(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY) = 1 
             THEN amtdue ELSE 0 END) 30days,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(
                      MONTH, 
                      LAST_DAY(invoicedate) + INTERVAL 1 DAY, 
                      LAST_DAY(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY) = 0 
             THEN amtdue ELSE 0 END) current,
    SUM(amtdue) total
FROM 
    quotes
GROUP BY 
    company;
```

**Explanation**

With the help of LAST_DAY() we'll get the last day of the month. We add one day on both sides, so we get the first of the next month. That helps us to get the difference between today and the invoicedate in whole months, where whole month is defined as

- invoicedate is in the current month, then 0
- invoicedate is in the last month, then 1
- invoicedate is even older, then > 1

Then we sum up the values, if they fall under this category.

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39653/3)

Comment: THANK YOU VMAI!! You're a genius. BTW I live in South Africa.

Comment: Thanks for the compliments. I'm glad I could help you. I thought first current ones were those of today or later and the 6th of August was for me (and for you of course) yesterday ... But on a closer look I saw the scheme "current month, last month, elder"

Answer (score 0):

You can get the required data in the query and just display using php... check query and modify accordingly...

```
select company, 
      sum(case when datediff(now(),invoicedate)>60 then amtdue else 0 end) 60days,
      sum(case when datediff(now(),invoicedate)<=60 and datediff(now(),invoicedate)>=30 then amtdue else 0 end) 30_60days,
      sum(case when datediff(now(),invoicedate)<30 then amtdue else 0 end) Current,
      sum(amtdue) Total
From YourTable
Group by Company;
```